# Google Chrome bookmarks to Google bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

Is there a way to move your bookmarks in chrome to Google's online bookmarks feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Information from Google

> Google Chrome bookmarks are separate
>   from those saved in Google Bookmarks.
>   While it's currently not possible to
>   automatically sync these two sets of
>   bookmarks, you can use a bookmarklet
>   to easily create Google Bookmarks in
>   Google Chrome.

- http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=100215

Last dev release has bookmarks sync support, but not with Google Bookmarks. It using Google Doc for storage.

Answer (score -1):

Export bookmarks from Chrome steps as I read from a [paper writing](http://www.research-service.com/):

1. Open Chrome.
2. Click on Chrome's tool icon to open the tools menu, and then select Bookmark Manager.

   Chrome's Bookmark Manager window will open.
3. In Chrome's Bookmark Manager window, click on the Tools item, and then select Export bookmarks.... A Save As window will appear.
4. In the Save As window, select a location on your computer to store the exported bookmarks file.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to send the bookmarks to the Google Bookmarks.

Comment: Fottopic- Unreleated answer to question