# How to sync Google Chrome Web Browser and Google Bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

**[Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)** has its own **[bookmarks](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/03/25/bookmarks-checker-for-google-chrome/)** that are synced across browsers using Google Docs. And **[Google](http://google.com)** also have **[Google Bookmarks](http://www.google.com/bookmarks)** that works very well with [google search](http://www.google.com) in itself. *It has been a long discussion in many places on why they don't get along.*

I know [similar questions](https://superuser.com/questions/129410/force-chrome-to-sync-bookmarks) have been asked, but I want to leave this open until a good solution comes around, unlike [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/38212/google-chrome-bookmarks-to-google-bookmarks/38229#38229).

So, is the **perfect** way to sync [google chrome bookmarks and google bookmarks](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=77fb3b55cbb73bde&hl=en) already born?

<sup>Next step: sync with delicious!</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing of this matters (to me) anymore since Google Plus was born. I believe it's now just a matter of time until all the rest gets merged into it.

To me, bookmarks were simply a way to mark what I like and maybe being able to find it later. Most of the times, I wouldn't ever bother about that link again and my bookmarks would just bloat up.

I never really organized or categorized and, even if I did, links would easily get broken after few years.

So, G+ is a way to mark / favorite / bookmark links in which I can easily see and find them again if I need to. Plus it is meant to work exactly as described, with the addendum that it will also show up on my search results and shared with my circles. The only thing lacking here is the ability to sync with my chrome bookmarks (which I don't use any longer) and google bookmarks. Both should probably be merged somehow, eventually.

Comment: And how's G+ relevant to bookmarks sync?

Comment: @dnbrv I hope my edit answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome its self has syncing built in. Simply go to Preferences --> Personal Stuff --> Set Up Sync. You can sync bookmarks, extensions, themes, etc.

Comment: Not what I meant at all. See if you get my point now it's edited.

Comment: @Cawas: You asked about syncing google chrome bookmarks, that's the answer I gave. Also, you don't need to use so many emoticons and the amount of bold you use is extremely unnecessary.

Comment: seriously? Then never mind.